# Is the overhead of serializing and deserializing POJOs a good reason for using Infinispan over Memcached or Redis for caching POJOs?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, infinispan

I need to cache different user and application data on a daily basis.

Context:

- no experience with caches
- working on a java web application that sends news articles to users displayed in a user-feed format
- `MySQL` backend
- `Java` middle tier using `Hibernate` and `Jersey`

I've checked out different cache technologies, and it seems like `Memcached` or `Redis` are the most used technologies in use cases similar to mine -- many reads and writes i.e. `Facebook`, `Twitter`, etc.

But I have to serialize objects before I cache them using the two above cache systems. It seemed like an unnecessary step to cache just a POJO, so I checked out POJO caches and stumbled upon `JBOSS`'s `Infinispan`.

Does anyone have any good reasons why I shouldn't use `Infinispan` over `Memcached` or `Redis` over the serialization, and subsequent deserialization, overhead concern?

Comment: Memcached and Redis are distributed key/value stores used as Cache. You can't get around serialization using a distributed Infinispan cache.

Comment: @mp911de but doesn't Infinispan cache java objects without having to serialize them?

Comment: True if running Infinispan in local-mode w/o replication. If so, then EhCache or Guava Cache are more lightweight choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Infinispan works in clustered mode, or when it has to offload data to external stores, it will have to face Serialization.

The good news is:
 - you'll avoid any serialization costs unless it has to go somewhere else
 - its own serialization mechanism is far more efficient than Java's standard serialization mechanism (and nicely customizable)

Memcached and Redis are "external" caching solutions, while with Infinispan you can keep the same Java instance cached. If this is a good or bad thing depends on your architecture specifics.

Although commonly you'll want to use a hybrid solution: use Infinispan for your in-JVM needs, cap its memory usage, have it offload what can't be fit locally to an external store, and it's easy to have it offload the extra stuff to either Redis, Memcached, another Infinispan cluster, or several other alternatives.

Your benefit is transparent integration with some popular frameworks (i.e. Hibernate) and that it can handle the serialization efficiently for you - if and when it's needed as it might need to happen in background.

Comment: why would I want to use a caching solution other than `Infinispan` to offload data to external stores if I'm already using `Infinispan`? couldn't i use another `Infinispan` instance in clustered mode to do the same thing?

Comment: Yes you can. In fact it's a common choice. It just isn't the primary reason to choose Infinispan, as if all you need is a non-clustered, external Cache then they are all pretty much interchangeable.